Импортирование таблицы с условием
Есть две таблицы, в первой отображается по вертикали в столбце А - Фамилии, в строке 1 отображаются даты, на пересечении Фамилии и Даты мы ставим число от 1 - 8 (можем оставить и ячейку пустой).

Требуется заполнить таблицу 2 данными с условием, что выводится ФИО и сумма часов, в периоде от и до (столбец B).

Таблицы созданы в разных документах, пробовал делать через importrage, но не получилось.

Чтобы соответствовать правилам сайта, покажите ваше решение (попытку) - формулу из A5, которая выдаёт "#VALUE!".

Таблица Database:

Таблица Report, Лист1:

A1=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ссылкаНаФайл/edit?usp=drive_link";"Лист1!A1:L4")

Таблица Report, Лист2:

A5=ARRAYFORMULA(HSTACK('Лист1'!A2:A4;BYROW('Лист1'!B2:L4;LAMBDA(i;СУММ(i*('Лист1'!B1:L1>=B1)*('Лист1'!B1:L1<=B2))))))

Нужно только вставить ссылку на таблицу Database.

Добрый день! Две таблицы из задания разные, первая таблица получена посредствам применения формулы =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(B1:AE1 &"|"&A2:A4 & "|" & B2:AE4);"|");"Select * where Col3 is not null")). В таблице по вертикали отображаются помощники, а по горизонтали дата, на пересечении мы ставим количество часов. Применив формулы выше получилась таблица из задания, вот ее требуется импортировать в другую с условием подсчета общей суммы часов.

Непонятно. В вопросе всё написано чётко: получить из одной таблицы другую. На это дан ответ. Если вопрос задан неправильно, то переделайте его в таком же чётком виде: это дано, это нужно получить. История появления данных не нужна, так как она не влияет на решение. Постарайтесь более полно представить данные в исходной таблице. Судя по комментарию, даты могут повторяться с разными фамилиями. Если это так, то покажите или опишите это.

Согласен, моя ошибка, подкорректировал

Ответ обновлён.

И чего, как результат?

Спасибо, вот только сел смотреть)

Спасибо огромное, работаееет!
